# Error installing juno eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

Last week I downloaded the new version of Eclipse, juno version.
I just tried to install Glassfish 3.1 and got the following error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was: (profile = epp.package.jee, org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect phase =, operand =, action =).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle, oracle.eclipse.tools.doc.javaee5, 1.0.0.201201241920.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 699d173f277d25db59d2b339a1e9098b and found 2887a201d2514c6b8322c5f630be0887.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle, oracle.eclipse.tools.doc.javaee6, 1.0.0.201201241920.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 089c09298729b38ac585f25f054477a5 and found 85033b5cbc613a8c6a5612c0cc91179b.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle, oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish, 5.0.1.201201241920.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 26c38ca1a321d9b1b1ca3271d777ee75 and found 472830c9576aad4b375175bc39fa9d4e.
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature, oracle.eclipse.tools.juno.glassfish, 2.0.1.201201241920.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: fbef299b507f02fcab8887c108e82434 and found a10465b7694743e7df1fb779b38a7e3b.
```

What does this error mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried downloading it again? Seems like a download problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issues installing/upgrading were solved unchecking the box “Contact all update sites during install to find required software”.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround: try installing glassfish+glassfish tools manually (Help -> Install New Software...), update site is http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/juno.

This installs the whole app server but you can delete it later and add your own.

Comment: That site redirects to http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/eclipse/juno/ which is empty

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this may be a bug ([reported](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383293)) with glassfish itself. Perhaps by now (a year later) it has been addressed. You might check in and see if the glassfish plugin has been fixed. Best wishes!